# Success to register but fail to save the session

Tags: php, session

I want to save session after user registers their account. It is successful before this, but when I try again today, it's failing.

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password   = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "select * from customer where Email = '".$email."'";
$rs = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$numRows = mysqli_num_rows($rs);

if($numRows  > 0 ){
    echo "Email has been used";
}
else {
    $options = array("cost"=>4);
    $hashPassword = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT,$options);
    $sql = "insert into customer (Email, Password) value('".$email."', '".$hashPassword."')";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    if($result) {
        $_SESSION["Email"] = $result["Email"];
        $_SESSION["Name"] = $result["Name"];
        header('Location: ../index.php');
    }
    else {
        echo "Cant";
    }
}`
```

How can solve this issue?

Comment: where do you call `session_start`?

Comment: write `session_start()` before set session variable...

Comment: i already call session_start at my header file, that will included for all my php file.

Comment: do you calling header page on this page ...?

Comment: yes, i called the header page. Is it related with hash password? because i also cant login even the user is registered.

Answer (score 3):

The error is that you are calling the variable that dont have values.

try the code below:

```html
$sql = "insert into customer (Email, Password) value('".$email."', '".$hashPassword."')";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    if($result) {
     $get_saved_user=mysqli_query($db,"select * from customer where Email='".$email."'");
     $user = mysqli_fetch_array($get_saved_user,MYSQLI_ASSOC);     
        $_SESSION["Email"] = $user["Email"];
        $_SESSION["Name"] = $user["Name"];
        header('Location: ../index.php');
    }
```

Comment: can not. still didn't save the value

Comment: the NAME field. you're calling it but you dont insert any value on it.

Comment: are you sure you have called teh session_start() already? can you try to call it again before $_SESSION["Email"] = $user["Email"];

Comment: its works. thanks a lots. just a few mistake i make during repair the code.